# Python Cron Job Fails Because Modules Are not Found

Tags: python, cron

I'm running a Python script on my server using a cron job:

```
/usr/bin/python/home/JohnDoe/scripts/Sample.py
```

I get an error saying

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/JohnDoe/scripts/Sample.py", line 2, in <module>
    import gspread
ImportError: No module named gspread\
```

Is there an easy way to run my third-party modules?

Comment: Is your cronjob running as the JohnDoe user? If not, then modules installed for that user only won't be read, unless you modify the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable, or `sys.path` in the script, to have the right target directory in

Comment: (The more portable option would be to install the module for the user running the cronjob, or to set up a virtual environment and activate that)

Comment: @SimonFraser how do I install python on my web service though? I'm using a shared server

Comment: When you say 'install python', do you mean the module? It would depend on the service you're using, it may let you install things with `pip` or give a file containing the list of things that should be installed